# How to bind desIndex to sort values in angular-ui-tree?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-tree

I'm using [angular-ui-tree](https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree).

The object I have in my treeview has a sort index. I am looking for a way to bind this sort index to the desIndex of the treeview scope, using something similar to this:

```
ui-tree-desIndex="node.sortIndex"
```

desIndex is the treeview node's index and node.sortIndex is my object's index.

I want it to sort my list by my objects' values, and when I move an object in the treeview the scope will update that object's index like this:

```
<div ui-tree="treeOptions" callbacks="treeOptions">
    <ol ui-tree-nodes="" data-nodrop-enabled="true" ng-model="rootNodeLst" callbacks="treeOptions" id="tree-root">
        <li ng-repeat="node  ui-tree-desIndex="node.sortIndex" in rootNodeLst" callbacks="treeOptions" ui-tree-node ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'"></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

The code above isn't working, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
<li ng-repeat="node  ui-tree-desIndex="node.sortIndex" in rootNodeLst" callbacks="treeOptions" ui-tree-node ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'"></li>
```

To this

```
<li ng-repeat="node in rootNodeLst" ui-tree-desIndex="node.sortIndex" callbacks="treeOptions" ui-tree-node ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'"></li>
```

For starters, to get your `ng-repeat` working.

Then, if `ui-tree-desIndex` does not get the value set, you can try:

`ui-tree-desIndex="{{node.sortIndex}}"` or `ng-attr-ui-tree-desIndex="{{node.sortIndex}}"`

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/w3nb3L1g/) JSFiddle.

Comment: I am indeed sry that i mess up my repeater, but the `ui-tree-desIndex="node.sortIndex"'` was just a sample of what i think i could be. the ui-tree-desIndex isn't something that works.

Answer (score 0):

Funny thing.

Found out that the way im building the treeview with the nested html modify my $index to show this sort number, so, anyway. thanks for your time and helå